# Error:SlashCommandBuilder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am getting 'SlashCommandBuilder is not a constructor' error my codes are below

I would be very happy if you could help, thanks in advance

```
const { Wordle} = require('discord-gamecord');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('wordle')
    .setDescription("Play the wordle game!"), 
    async execute (interaction) {
        
        const Game = new Wordle({ 
            message: interaction, 
            isSlashGame: false,
            embed: {
                title: 'Wordle',
                color: '#5865F2'
            },
            customword: null,
            timeoutTime: 60000,
            winMessage: 'You won! The word was **(word)**', 
            loseMessage: 'You lost! The word was **{word}**',
            playerOnlyMessage: 'Only {player} cam ise these buttons'
        });
        
        Game.startGame();
        Game.on('gameOver', result => {
            return;
        })
    }    
}
```